# Simple kubernetes deployment on minikube with helm 3 not working (cant reach app)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I am trying to deploy a simple FLASK app (python web framework) on a Kubernetes cluster. I am using minikube.

Here's my Helm 3 stuff:

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask-app-deployment
  labels:
    app: flask-app
    some: label
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask-app-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flask-app-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: flask-app-container
          image: flask_app:0.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - name: app
              containerPort: 5000
              protocol: TCP
          securityContext: # root access for debugging
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            runAsUser: 0
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flak-app-service
  labels:
    service: flask-app-services
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      protocol: TCP
      name: https
  selector:
    app: flask-app-pod
```

Chart:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: flask-app
type: application
version: 0.0.1
appVersion: 0.0.1
```

I deploy this by doing `helm install test-chart/ --generate-name`.

Sample output of `kubectl get all`:

```
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/flask-app-deployment-d94b86cc9-jcmxg   1/1     Running   0          8m19s

NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/flak-app-service   NodePort    10.98.48.114   <none>        5000:30317/TCP   8m19s
service/kubernetes         ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          7d2h

NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/flask-app-deployment   1/1     1            1           8m19s

NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/flask-app-deployment-d94b86cc9   1         1         1       8m19s
```

I exec'd into the pod to check if it's listening on the correct port, looks fine (netstat output):

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/python3
```

My Dockerfile should be fine. I can create a container and call the app then running a "normal" dcker container.

Must be something stupid. What am I not seeing here?

I would expect to be able to go `https://localhost:30317` which gets forwarded to the service listening on port 5000 internally, which forwards it into the pod that also listens on port 5000.

Comment: Can you please post the output of ```kubectl describe service flak-app-service```? Also check if there are endpoints to it. If not then follow the below answer but I'm sure your selector looks good. Then exec in to the pod and run locally your curl command on localhost with the container port to check if everything is fine inside the container. Also post that output too. Thanks.

Comment: Try the same thing with docker-desktop (if you're on windows or mac that is).

Comment: what do you mean with can't reach?

Answer (score 1):

To validate traffic you can use following as where it is breaking:

```
kubectl port-forward pods/flask-app-deployment-d94b86cc9-jcmxg 5000:12345
```

or

```
kubectl port-forward deployment/flask-app-deployment 5000:12345
```

or

```
kubectl port-forward service/flak-app-service 5000:12345
```

depending upon where you want to debug.

Also please validate by running `netstat -tunlp` whether your host is listening on the allotted port or not.

Hope this solves your error, or let me know if it does not.

Comment: The `selector:` needs to match the _pod's_ labels, which are in the `template: { metadata: { labels: { ... } } }` section; they match up correctly in the Deployment spec in the question.

Comment: aah i made a boo-boo sorry about that... editing my answer :)  :p